# What is the function of と in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 学生時代にもっと勉強すればよかった**と**、今ではとても残念だ。

This doesn't seem like the ～と...　pattern:

> Expresses the idea that when ～ arises or happens, it will definitely lead to ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24583/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25361/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45089/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, と is used to refer to the preceding phrase, or 学生時代にもっと勉強すればよかった. This is because we can consider that と is a part of と思う and that 思う is omitted from the sentence. Indeed, by inserting 思う, we can paraphrase the sentence as follows:

> (1) 学生時代にもっと勉強すればよかった**と**，今ではとても残念に**思う**．
>
> (I should have studied more in my school years. Now I deeply regret **that**.)

Now, for a quick understanding of how と works, consider a simplified version of sentence (1):

> (2) 学生時代にもっと勉強すればよかった**と**<s>，今ではとても残念に</s>**思う**．
>
> (I think **that** I should have studied more in my school years.)

In sentence (2), と is indeed used to refer to the preceding phrase.

Next, for a further understanding of how と works, consider an expanded version of sentence (1):

> (3) 学生時代にもっと勉強すればよかった**と**，今では`学生時代にもっと勉強しなかったことを`とても残念に**思う**．
>
> (I should have studied more in my school years. Now I deeply regret **that** `I did not study more in my school years`.)

In sentence (3), と is essentially used to refer to the preceding phrase. This is because what I deeply regret now, or `学生時代にもっと勉強しなかったこと`, can only be inferred from the phrase preceding と.